# Force inertia to use https request

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, inertiajs

[image]

My project is already live I'm using jetstream to login, laravel 8, inertiajs and vuejs 3 but when the user logs in he changes from https to http as in the image does anyone know how to force him to use only https

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @goyote not bro ;-;